# How to use PURGE option in Pyspark Snowflake Connector?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to use the PURGE option in pyspark-snowflake connector options? I am using the below configurations-

```py
df.write.mode('overwrite') \
        .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
        .options(sfURL=[url],
                 sfUser=[user],
                 sfDatabase=[database],
                 sfSchema=[schema],
                 sfWarehouse=[warehouse],
                 sfRole=[role],
                 pem_private_key=pkb) \
        .option('truncate_table', 'ON') \
        .option('usestagingtable', 'OFF') \
        .option('continue_on_error', 'on') \
        .option('purge', 'off') \
        .option('dbtable', [dbtable]) \
        .save()
```

But it seems like the temporary file that is being generated while loading data from py-spark to snowflake is getting deleted every time we are loading the data.
I read it in the snowflake documentation that if the purge option is off then it should not delete that file.
Please let me know how to use this option in spark snowflake connector.
Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering why do we have 3 people desperately asking for this now?

Comment: Can you try *.option("purge", "true")* and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

`df.write.mode('overwrite')`  change this to `df.write.mode('append')`  // overwrite will by default delete the existing files first and save the new files